# SAS do loops and macros

Tags: sas

I tried to develop the code and make sure that I will include the comparison with the newly extended average, however it does not work the way it should be.

can you please advise what needs to be done so that condition (value1 < saved_average and value2 < saved_average and value3 < saved_average) always tests against not saved_average but the newly created required_result variable?

```
Data want;
 Set have;
 If (value1 < value2 < value3) and (_n_ > 2) and (_n_ > max_recordnum) then do;
  max_recordnum = _n_ + 3;
  Saved_average = average1;
 End;
 Retain max_recordnum saved_average;
 If saved_average = . Then required_result = average1;
 Else required_result = saved_average;
 If (value1 < saved_average and value2 < saved_average and value3 < saved_average) and (_n_ > max_recordnums) and (_n_ > max_recordnum) then do;
  max_recordnums = _n_ + 3;
  Saved_average2 = average1;
 End;
 Retain max_recordnums saved_average2;
 If saved_average2 = .  And  saved_average = . Then required_result = average1;
 Else required_result = saved_average;
 If saved_average2 <> .  Then required_result = saved_average2;
Run;
```

Not certain why but all observations counters (underscore n underscore) turned to just n in the above code. Maybe because I'm typing this all in on the iPad.

I am quite new to SAS programming therefore would appreciate any input on the possible solution of the problem I have!

I have the following data:

```
value1       value2     value3     average1    required_result
1              9         12           7               7
8              6         9            6               7
4              7         10           2               7
6              2         1            8               7
.              .         .            .        
.              .         .            .
.              .         .            .
7              9         16           24              24
.              .          .            .              24
X              Y          Z            W
```

I need to do the following:

- If row n has got the following trend - value1 > value2> value3, then use the first encountered average1 value for the next 4 rows;
- after 4 rows calculate if value1 > value2 > value3 is true. If it is true then use the next first encountered average1 value for another 4 rows;
- repeat.

for example, in the first row value1 > value2> value3 (1 > 9 > 12) therefore we need to use average1 = 7 the next 4 rows starting from the first one.

can you please advise how this can be coded in SAS?

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve this yourself and post that code.  This isn't a code service; we're intending to help you with code you've written.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. That's the problem that at the moment I don't know where to start even.

Comment: Take a look at `retain` which allows you to "retain" same value from one row to another in data step. Also look at `_N_` -variable which gives you the number of row in data step.

Comment: What is the expected result if the required trend is false on the first (, fifth, and folowing) occurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well done on having a go yourself and welcome to the site. 
My answer is not the most elegant, but it solves your problem. You don't need macros or `_N_`, but `retain` comes handy.

Here is my code. You retain the average, and have a running count to make sure you retain it for the next four observations. After fourth observation, you need to reset your count and overage until the main condition is true again.

```
data ORIG_DATA;
    input value1   value2     value3     average1;
    cards;
1              9         12           7               
8              6         9            6               
4              7         10           2               
6              2         1            8               
.              .         .            .        
.              .         .            .
.              .         .            .
7              9         16           24              
.              .          .            .              
;
run;

data want (drop=obs_count);
    set Orig_data;
    retain carried_average;
    retain obs_count;

    if (obs_count le 0 or obs_count gt 4) and value1 lt value2 AND value2 lt value3 Then
        do;
            carried_average = average1;
            obs_count = 1;
        end;
    else if (obs_count ge 0 and obs_count le 4) then
        obs_count + 1;

    if obs_count gt 4 then
        do;
            carried_average = .;
        end;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Василий! This looks very good and quite elegant to me 

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Welcome to the site. :-)